# Preserve stacktrace of exceptions thrown inside MVC async controller methods

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have a webapi backend and a client consuming it. If the backend throws an exception it gets serialized as an HttpError. I am fully following the tutorial here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

On the client side I can deserialize the HttpError and read all the values included using "JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(myContentString)" - this is all working fine.

Now my first question is: How do I rethrow the exception on the client? Is there no such method as HttpError.Throw()?

Because I haven't found anything like that yet, I am creating a new custom exception and passing in all the relevant values including the stacktrace:

```
throw new MyException(myHttpError["Message"], myHttpError["StackTrace"]);
```

MyException overrides StackTrace and simply returns the string. This works fine in normal mvc controller methods BUT in async controller methods the standard ASP.NET error page is displaying the stacktrace to the "throw..." line from above and not the stacktrace that's actually kept inside the exception! So my second question is: How can I display the stacktrace that I set on my custom exception on the standard ASP.NET error page?

Comment: Are you sure you `override` `StackTrace`? Is the `override` keyword present?

Comment: It looks like you will find your stack trace in a HTML comment at the end of the page code. I have no idea why does it behave this way.

Comment: @svick: No, it's not present anywhere on the page (source).

Comment: @svick: Correction - you are right! I can see it down there - is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of the view file and it should output the stacktrace, under the normal error.

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    <h3>@Model.Exception.GetType().Name</h3>
    <pre>
        @Model.Exception.ToString()
    </pre>
    <p>
        thrown in @Model.ControllerName @Model.ActionName
    </p>
}
```